# Pass CTE to multiple postgres functions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression

In Postgres I want to "store" the current state of a table and call multiple functions with this current state. The idea is that if the data is altered between the calls to the functions that the functions still all use the same data.

The closest thing I got was;

```
WITH current_table AS (SELECT * FROM table)
  result1 AS (SELECT function1(current_table)),
  result2 AS (SELECT function2(current_table)),
  SELECT function3(current_table)
```

The functions do not return anything so result1 and result2 are not used. This does not work of course because CTEs can't be passed to functions in postgres as far as I know.

Is there an alternative for what I want to achieve? Also calling the functions nested inside the with statement is kind of ugly. Is there a better way?

I don't want to store the whole table in a temporary table.

I'm using plpgsql.

Comment: The table state will already be "static" while that code executes, you don't need to do anything - see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html

Comment: A CTE doesn't hold data, it's just a definition of a set of data like a View. The table is the ONLY thing in your database that holds data and the only operations that will cause that data to change are `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.

Comment: Thanks @eurotrash! So if I understand this correctly, any select statement inside the different functions will be performed in the exact same table?

Comment: Perhaps you should use a temporary table.